# Как сделать лупу для Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

Стоит задача сделать аналог "экранной лупы" для использования её на Canvas, на котором при этом можно рисовать.

Сохранённые точки подгружаются заранее из базы данных, их и нужно увеличить. Я не очень силён в Js, поэтому принялся искать готовое решение, но нашёл только варианты с использованием изображений, текста, либо статичного изображения загруженного в canvas.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Хотелось бы добиться примерно такого результата, при этом не используя изображение, а только заранее загруженные точки (они динамические).
Фрагмент кода не мой, взят из codepen.

```js
class Experience {
    constructor(container) {
        this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        container.appendChild(this.canvas);
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

        const fps = 60;//60
        this.fpsInterval = 1000 / fps;
        this.then = Date.now();
        
        this.point = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    this.distPoint = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    this.pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

        this.resize();
        this.bind();
        
        this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = "https://robindelaporte.fr/codepen/slide.jpg";
        
        this.image.onload = () => {
      this.loop();
        };
    }

    bind() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this), false);
        
        this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
        
        this.canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", this.onTouchMove.bind(this));

    }

    render() {
        this.clear();
        // this.context.save()
          this.context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        
        this.pos.x += (this.point.x - this.pos.x) * 0.2;
    this.pos.y += (this.point.y - this.pos.y) * 0.2;

    this.context.save();
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.canvas.height * 0.15, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    this.context.strokeStyle = "white";
    this.context.lineWidth = 6;
    // this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";
    this.context.stroke();
    this.context.closePath();
    this.context.clip();
        
        this.context.drawImage(
      this.image,
      -this.canvas.width * 0.2 +
        (this.canvas.width - this.canvas.width * 1.4) * (this.distPoint.x * 1), //0.05,
      -this.canvas.height * 0.2 +
        (this.canvas.height - this.canvas.height * 1.4) * (this.distPoint.y * 1), //0.05,
      this.canvas.width * 1.4,
      this.canvas.height * 1.4
    );
    // this.context.opacity = 1;

    this.context.restore();

    }

    loop() {
        this.raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));

        const now = Date.now();
        const delta = now - this.then;

        if (delta > this.fpsInterval) {
            // this.context.clearRect( 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height )
            this.render();
            this.then = now;
        }
    }
    
    onMouseMove(ev){
        var rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.point = {
      x:
        (ev.clientX - 7) - rect.left,
      y: (ev.clientY - 7) - rect.top
    };

    this.distPoint = {
      x: (this.point.x - this.canvas.width * 0.5) / this.canvas.width,
      y: (this.point.y - this.canvas.height * 0.5) / this.canvas.height
    };  
    }
    
    onTouchMove(ev){
        var rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.point = {
      x:
        ev.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
      y: ev.touches[0].clientY - rect.top
    };

    this.distPoint = {
      x: (this.point.x - this.canvas.width * 0.5) / this.canvas.width,
      y: (this.point.y - this.canvas.height * 0.5) / this.canvas.height
    };  
    }

    resize() {
        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.7;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerWidth * 0.7 / 1.77;
        this.screen = {
            center: { x: this.canvas.width / 2, y: this.canvas.height / 2 }
        };

        //this.reset();
    }
    
    clear(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }

    reset() {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.raf);
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        this.loop();
    }
}

const experience = new Experience(document.body);
```

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 7px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #00000038;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    left: 0;
    font-family: monospace;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

При редактировании этого кода под свою задачу столкнулся с проблемой, что этот код рисует лупу на самом canvas и отрисовывает изображение снова, что не очень подходит для динамических точек из бд (они мерцают)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать второй canvas для увеличения:

```js
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var zoom = document.getElementById("zoom");

// разрешения canvas
var scale = 1;

main.style.width = main.width + 'px';
main.style.height = main.height + 'px';
main.width = main.width * scale;
main.height = main.height * scale;

var ctx = main.getContext("2d")
var zoomCtx = zoom.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 1;

// Тут можно рисовать что угодно
ctx.fillRect(25 * scale, 25 * scale, 100 * scale, 100 * scale);
ctx.clearRect(45 * scale, 45 * scale, 60 * scale, 60 * scale);
ctx.strokeRect(50 * scale, 50 * scale, 50 * scale, 50 * scale);


main.addEventListener("pointermove", function(e) {
  zoomCtx.beginPath();
  zoomCtx.arc(50, 50, 30, Math.PI * 2, false);
  zoomCtx.strokeStyle = "white";
  zoomCtx.lineWidth = 6;
  zoomCtx.stroke();
  zoomCtx.closePath();
  zoomCtx.clip();

  zoomCtx.fillStyle = "white";
  zoomCtx.fillRect(0, 0, zoom.width, zoom.height);
  zoomCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  zoomCtx.drawImage(main,
    (e.x - 25 + document.scrollingElement.scrollLeft) * scale,
    (e.y - 25 + document.scrollingElement.scrollTop) * scale,
    10 * scale, 10 * scale, 20, 20, 80, 80);


  zoom.style.top = (e.pageY - 50) + "px"
  zoom.style.left = (e.pageX - 50) + "px"
  zoom.style.display = "block";
});

main.addEventListener("pointerout", function() {
  zoom.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="main" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="zoom" width="100" height="100" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;pointer-events: none; display:none"></canvas>
```

UPD
Воизбежание замыленностей увеличено разрешение canvas

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, это хорошо работает, но появилась другая проблема, линии выглядят размытыми в лупе, это каким-то образом можно исправить? https://i.ibb.co/HpzR92y/photo-2023-07-24-20-39-19.jpg Тут просто супер мелкий пиксель-арт

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn Исправил ответ

Comment: scale действительно помогает от размытия, но при этом уменьшает размер точек на основном canvas. Я нашёл свойство imageSmoothingEnabled, и установил значение false, это работает супер круто без уменьшения точек на основном canvas. Спасибо огромное, вы очень помогли.